# What is the difference in meaning between a "variable" and a "parameter" in a given equation?

Tags: meaning

Especially in mathematical usage, do *variable* and *parameter* mean the same thing? If not, can you explain the difference in meaning and usage?

Comment: *Variable* and *parameter* have clearly defined meanings in specific contexts. What these words mean in general English usage may not necessarily apply in mathematical, programming and other scientific/ technical contexts. As for 'mathematical usage', No, they do not mean the same thing.

Comment: So far, the answers are in the context of programming.  For meanings in mathematics (unless someone provides one here) ask in a mathematics site...

Comment: In logic, Richmond Thomason uses *parameter* to mean free variable. It is an unknown individual referred to only in a limited context, which context may be subject to certain assumptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in mathematical statistics is very [clear-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter).  Suppose you have a set of data which you believe behaves according to a quadratic law

> *y* = *a x*<sup>2</sup> + *b* + *c*.

So you have observed lots of pairs of values (*x,y*)—with errors—and you are trying to estimate *a*, *b* and *c*. Then *x* and *y* are called *variables* and *a, b,* and *c* are called *parameters.*

In general mathematical terminology, the definitions are essentially the same. For functions, the inputs and outputs are *variables,* and other values in the definition of the function that might possibly change are called *parameters.* Here, however, you are not trying to estimate the parameters from observed values of the variables, so the definitions are somewhat fuzzier; you could treat the same object as a variable and as a parameter in two different sections of the same mathematical paper.

Note that the above definition does not apply to [parametric equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation), where the variables in a function are defined in terms of a parameter which does not appear in the function.

Comment: Would you say than if I see y = y(x) then a,b,c are parameters, whereas if I see y = y(a,b,c) then x is a parameter?

Comment: @Kavka: I would.

Comment: Your answer seems only to add to the confusion. While you seem very clear about which is a variable and which a parameter in your example, you are thoroughly confused as to why they happen to be so, because you do not understand what actually defines a variable and a parameter in mathematical use.

Comment: @Kris: then you should write your own answer. See the Wikipedia article on [parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter), in particular, the section on **Mathematical Functions**. Except for the first paragraph of this section (in which I can't understand what they're saying) and the mention of *parametric equations* (where the word "parameter" is used for variables that play a somewhat different role), my definition is the same as theirs.

Comment: I have not attempted to answer because the answer is not related to the English language and not simple. However, misconceptions need to be avoided. Which is why I tried to clarify that the definitions are more complex than you imply. see: 'Note that the above definition does not apply to parametric equations, ...' from your own reference.

Comment: @Kris: like many words in English, "parametric" is used for several different things in mathematics. The definition above is the most common usage. Another definition is the one used in parametric equations and parametric curves.

Answer (score 5):

Note: This answer is with regards to programming, not mathematics.

*Variable* is a term used generically refer to a storage location, usually in memory, holding data for a program.  (Sources: [C# language definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691160%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29)).  I like this explanation from [about.com](http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/p/variable.htm):

> Imagine a very large warehouse with lots of storage bays, tables, shelves, special rooms etc. These are all places where you can store something. Lets imagine we have a crate of beer in the warehouse. Where exactly is it located?

The variable is the location of the crate, given a symbolic name like "beerLocation" so you can easily reference it.

Of course, *variable* in the literal sense means "able to vary", so in [some contexts](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_Between_Variable_And_constant) this can be used as a means of differentiating between data that can be altered (variable) and data that is fixed (constant).

A *parameter* is a special type of variable, used in reference to data passed to functions/subroutines/macros.  Sources: [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29).   There is some [subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters) between parameters and arguments, but they are often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 2):

Variable refers to it has a changing values or context . A parameter is a special kind of variable, used in a subroutine to refer to one of the pieces of data provided as input to the subroutine.These pieces of data are called arguments. An ordered list of parameters is usually included in the definition of a subroutine, so that, each time the subroutine is called, its arguments for that call can be assigned to the corresponding parameters.

Comment: A parameter is a variable? Always? Also, see @Apoorva.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to 2 dimension:(viz. x, y where f:X->Y:x|->y)

Your dependant variable is f(X) or simply stated, random function output.
Your independent variable, X, has 2 criteria.
a) With respects to the experiment, program or whatever your working on, the scientist/programmer must be changing it( viz. collecting data on velocity Y by changing time X). 
b) We choose our variable to add to out understanding of the program/experiment and to simplify functions( by grouping variables in terms of parameters).

Graphically, it is easy to identify variables, since they are always on the axis.

Parameter: this can be a arbitrary or fixed constant (depending on the description and definition of a function e.g. You will not use arbitrary powers when defining a parabola, but you will when expressing a polynomial of degree n) used with variables to express a function or family of functions. Consider F(x) = ax^2 + e^c: we have parameters a, 2 and d where d= e^c. This example shows that parameters are also used to simplify expressions i.e F(x) = aX^2 + d, a general solution to a particular family of parabolas.

Now in statistics, due to the importance of seperating our standard parameters(like population variance and mean) from any other( and in so doing, perhaps identifying a set familiar distribution like gamma, binomial, normal etc.) we add the parameters in our functions arbitrary argument( if you're a programmer, I'm refering to the function prototype). 
F(X;a,2,d) in the above example.

As for parametric functions, please refer to the graph example and b) section of dependent variable criteria.
Even though X(t) and t are both candidates to be variables, in some situations choosing t doesn't make sence. If the purpose of a experiment is to test for dependancy between sex and height, X(t1,t2,...,tn) might be the variable hight, but if we know X depends on t1 = # of hours spent exercising, I'm not going to make that my dependent variable. Even if that is the only parameter of X, the purpose of the experiment is sex vs height, so graphically I want a sex vs. height graph. Now you may think that, siince t1 is varying, it's not a constant and hence a variable. In a sence this us true, but this is just the difference between a variable and a arbitrary constant.
Viz. Y= 3; Y = sin(3). In both cases Y is a variable and 3 is obviously a parameter, so if mathimaticions take arbitrary parameters X= sin(t) , Y = cos(t) and call r(t) =  a parametric equation they have every right to do so. t is not a variable. We are collecting data about X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms, a parameter defines particular characteristic of your model, system, framework or function etc. It may be variable, like the size of the bicycle wheel if you are building one from scratch but the wheel would never be missed, because that's a parameter the defines the architecture of the bike, without it there won't be bicycle. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Variable

In the field of mathematics, a variable defines as an element connected to a number, known as an estimation of the variable that is self-estimated, not completely determined, or ambiguous. The expression “variable” originates from the way that, when the argument (additionally called the “variable of the Function”) changes, then the estimate changes accordingly.

Parameter

A parameter, by and large, is an entity that can help in connecting or grouping a specific framework. That is, a parameter is a component of a system that is helpful, or basic. Inside and over different fields, watchful refinement must be kept up of the diverse utilizations of the term parameter and of different terms frequently connected with it.
The reference of this content is https://researchpedia.info/difference-between-variable-and-parameter/

Answer (score -3):

Variable is a parameter whose value might change during the execution of code. Parameters are values that are passed to a function. It could be either variable or constant.

Comment: Are all variables parameters?

Comment: In programming sense i would say yes.. All variables are parameters but the reverse is not true i.e., all parameters are not variables.they might also be constants.

Comment: A program may use its own internal variables in addition to parameters passed to it -- right?

Comment: It depends on what parameters you would wish to pass to a particular method or a function.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct - parameters are normally used to refer to data passed into a given scope, whereas variables are data declared within a given scope.  They are not parameters because they are not passed in.

Comment: You can also pass that data (variable) to  a method and what ever you are passing to a method is called parameter it could be a variable or a constant. like main(){ int const a=5 ; int b} now a becomes a constant and b is a variable.. so if u have method public int add(int ,int) what ever is inside the brackets after add are the parameters you would be passing to the add method.so it could be either a which is constant or b which is a variable.Refer http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node4.html